# Maps API: how to fade the base layer?

Tags: here-api

I created an app using the HERE Maps API for JavaScript that lets the user view GeoJSON shapes using the H.data.geojson.Reader class.  It's working great, but now I need to let the user fade the map's base layer so that it is brighter or darker than the GeoJSON layer.  After a thorough read of the online docs, I can't find a way to accomplish this.

Here are visual examples:

[The current behavior (i.e. base layer + GeoJSON layer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqtXA.png)

[Mockup image of base layer partially faded to white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTcOt.png)

[Mockup image of base layer partially faded to black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuEra.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways.

1. Overlay a transparent layer on the map using this [example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/data/custom-tile-overlay)
2. Change the map style to make the colors translucent. If you are using the default map style, you will have to change all the layer colors to rgba(x,x,x,0.2)
   You can try this with this [example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/styles/change-style-at-runtime). If you want to load up a complete new style, try the [map style editor](https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/#15/52.530903/13.384838).